# "for loop" to run rsync on relevant folders only

Tags: bash, loops, syntax, copy, rsync

I have a folder contains around 650 folders (source), I generated a list of the relevant folders i want (final.txt).
i am trying to use a "for loop" to copy only the relevant sub-folders to a new location (target).
i keep getting the original content of the "source" copied to the "target".

i run:

```
for var in `cat final.txt` ; do rsync -ah $var source/ target/ ; done
```

I tried different syntax but can't seem to get what I need.
what am i doing wrong?

I expect to copy only the folders which name is in the final.txt list copied to the target (all "names" in the file are a single word, matching to some of the folder names for exactly)

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: That being said, afaik `rsync` has an option/flag to read from a file, otherwise I'd use an array to store the data from the text file. `mapfile -t directories < file.txt; rsync -ah "${directories[@]}"  target/` , Untested though.

Comment: hi. i ran both.

same result :)

Comment: `Usage: rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... DEST`. If you don't want `source/` why are you copying it?

Comment: I want only spacific subfolders that are inside the 'source' folder. I have them listed in my txt file

Comment: Dident get it to run...

Answer (score 0):

ok after messing around I should have ran this (it works)

```
for var in `cat final.txt` ; do rsync -ah source/$var target/ ; done
```

Comment: `for v in $(cat file); do ...; done` may be better as: `while IFS= read -r v; do ...; done <file` or `mapfile -t a <file; for v in "${a[@]}"; do ...; done` . The `for` version performs wordsplitting which corrupts whitespace from the input.

Comment: It is generally good practice to quote use of variables (`source/"$var"`). In this case it is safe, but only because the `for` already did (possibly undesired) wordsplitting.